# How to create a linked folder in Eclipse Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have imported a project test1 which contains two weird linked folders. (at least for me they are weird :)

They look like this [image] but I can't see any content, one can't open them.

[image]

Now I would like to write my own project and need to create these two folders but I do not have any idea how I do this.

When I go on the first linked folder of the imported project i see:

```
Path: /ImportedProject/org_taptwo_android_widget_viewflow_src

Location: _android_org_taptwo_android_widget_viewflow_7cfa4d63/src
```

I get many errors if I do not have these two linked folders. Can anybody help and tell me how to create these in my project?

I tried copy paste, but that did not work
I also tried to link source in the Java Build Path -> Source but that links the source folder and shows all the files and is somehow different from what I need.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste "Linked Folders".

(I can't figure out how to create them, so I just copied an existing one)